# Does Access Allow Rich Text formatting of attached ODBC tables?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a customer using Access as a front end for attached MySQL tables. The customer wants to be able to use rich text formatting in memo fields (specifically, bolding selected words). When I try to alter the properties of attached table MediumText fields to "Rich Text", Access won't allow me to save the changes. Access won't allow me to bold selected words in form fields referencing these fields either.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by doing the following:

My MySQL table has columns

ID - int, AUTO_INCREMENT, Primary Key
Comments - mediumtext

I created an ODBC linked table in Access that points to the MySQL table. I created a form in Access, bound it to the linked table, and then added the two fields. When I switched to Form view I saw

[image: FormView1.png]

I switched back to Design view, selected the Text Box for the [Comments] field and changed its `Text Format` property from 'Plain Text' to 'Rich Text'.

[image: DesignView.png]

That produced the following warning:

[image: Warning.png]

After I clicked "Yes" I switched back to Form view and then I saw

[image: FormView2.png]

I made some edits to the text to confirm that they were correctly saved back to the MySQL table and displayed correctly when I re-visited that record.